# Cannot engage module rampart, not sending security details

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, ws-security, eclipse-wtp, rampart

I'm using eclipse with WTP plugin for creating a client to call secure web service.

I have used web service client wizard to generate the client and now I want to configure apache rampart in the eclipse project to call the service protected with username token

the error is "can not engage module rampart". 
-------- update ----

After getting the cannot engage module rampart corrected, I'm getting folllowing:

```
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: rampart-1.4 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/rampart-1.4.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.5.2 - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.5.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/E:/Source Code Evaluations/axis2Codes/myAxisClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://192.168.9.120:9443/services/HelloService.HelloServiceHttpsEndpoint/]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
```

_----------------------------------- update end -------------------

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases when you are not using axis repositories for development and using eclipse, you don't need to manually engage the module, you can just place the rampar and rahas jars to class path and it will work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Prashant, can you please share where I can find the 2 jars. Also I kept rampart-core 1.6 as dependency via maven. Is it not enough? Please suggest. Thanks Chakri

Comment: You can find both jars through google. Referencing through maven is fine, you just need to make sure your class path in eclipse editor (if you are using it) is properly resolving to it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably not copied `rampart-1.5.mar` (or newer) to axis2 `modules` directory.

Comment: Hi, I got the error cleared, thanks, but rampart is not sending security info, any idea why?

Comment: While you use `https` you should check on the server side if your query is received. Maybe server want you to use SSL with client certificate? You must check 192.168.9.120 web server logs. If it is Apache then look at `/var/logs/error.log` and `/var/logs/ssl.log`

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar.
I set my stub to point to a local http address instead of the remote webservice, ie:
"http://localhost:88/onca/soap3"

I then used TCPMon to check what was being set
Listen # 88
Target HostName 127.0.0.1
TargetPort 8080

This let me confirm that the SOAP request I was sending was what I expected.
I also copied the request into SOAP UI and checked it could be sent successfully from there.